# What is this icon that Putin touches/kisses at monument of St.Vladimir?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, russia

The Russian Federation (along with some other Slavic nations), [recently celebrated the 1,030th anniversary of the Christianization of the Rus'](https://www.rt.com/news/434531-russia-ukraine-belarus-christianity/), which included a liturgy at the monument to Vladimir the Great near the Kremlin.

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1428&v=jvpmYH9pF6E) (time- 23:45), President Putin (followed by the Patriarch) is seen bending forward and touching/kissing some icon/relic encased in a gilded box.

What exactly is this gilded box (or the item contained within it)?

---

Granted, since this event is also a tribute to St.Vladimir, I guess this is some relic associated with him? (I'm not entirely sure though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the news, https://foma.ru/na-1030-letie-kreshheniya-rusi-v-kremle-vpervyie-sovershili-liturgiyu-pod-otkryityim-nebom.html a shrine with the part of relics of St. Vladimir from the Christ the Savior church in Moscow was brought in before the Liturgy in Kremlin so I guess then it was carried to the monument of St. Vladimir where Putin venerated it.